# How can I calculate the Cimon in a DC-DC converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I would like to use LT3649 IC, but I don't know how can I calculate the following in the datasheet: Output current monitoring and regulation section in page 10. The datasheet: [LT3649](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3649fb.pdf)
If I use 10k resistor for Rimon and 10nF capacitor for Cimon how can I calculate the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the datasheet, at page 10.

\begin{equation}
C_{IMON}R_{IMON} \geq \frac{1.59}{f_{SW}}
\end{equation}

Using your values,

\begin{equation}
(10 \text{ nF})(10 \text{ k}\Omega) \geq \frac{1.59}{f_{SW}} \Rightarrow f_{SW} \geq 15.9 \text{ kHz}
\end{equation}

The switching frequency is set by \$R_T\$ as described at page 11.

\begin{equation}
f_{SW} = \frac{10^5}{R_T \text{ (k}\Omega)} \Rightarrow R_T < 6.289\text{ k}\Omega
\end{equation}

Comment: If i want to use 1MHz frequency how do the values change?

Comment: Then, \$ C_{IMON}R_{IMON} \geq 0.00000159 \$. For example, choosing \$ C_{IMON} = 10 nF \$, you need \$ R_{IMON} \geq 0.00000159/10n = 159 \Omega \$, which is pretty low. I suggest you use \$ C_{IMON} = 1 nF, R_{IMON} = 1.8k\Omega \$